# javaScript: mouseenter/out event javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, ajax

I want to make hover effect whit javaScript I use mouseenter and mouseout event to make button show  the content in mouse enter and remove content in mouse out, the problem is the content in mouse enter disappear if the content contains element, but if the content not contains element its work.

```js
 const button = document.querySelector("button"),
                dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");

            button.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
                dropdown.classList.add("active")

                dropdown.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
                    dropdown.classList.add("active")
                })

                button.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
                    dropdown.classList.remove("active")

                    dropdown.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
                        dropdown.classList.remove("active")
                    })
                })
            })
```

```css
 * {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            body {
                display: grid;
                place-items: center;
                height: 100vh;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            button {
                padding: 1em;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .dropdown {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100PX;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: red;
                bottom: 52%;
                display: none;
            }

            .dropdown.active {
                display: block;
            }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>
            Hover Me
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Css works better in this case

Comment: You bind events inside other events so it is going to add tons of event listeners. This is going to cause issues. addEventListener is adds, it does not replace events.

Answer (score 1):

Please add you can exchange mouseenter with mouseover
It also would works. It's ok?

```js
 const button = document.querySelector("button"),
                dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");

            button.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
                dropdown.classList.add("active")

                dropdown.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
                    dropdown.classList.add("active")
                })

                button.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
                    dropdown.classList.remove("active")

                    dropdown.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
                        dropdown.classList.remove("active")
                    })
                })
            })
```

```css
* {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            body {
                display: grid;
                place-items: center;
                height: 100vh;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            button {
                padding: 1em;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .dropdown {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100PX;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: red;
                bottom: 52%;
                display: none;
            }

            .dropdown.active {
                display: block;
            }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>
            Hover Me
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to make hover effect whit javaScript in order to control the drop down in scroll –

Comment: Yes, you can just exchange mouseenter with mouseover

Comment: I m so sorry my reply was not directed to you I would answer another, thank you , you are the only one who understand me. You save my day, I didn't know was a difference between mouseenter and mouseover

Comment: That sounds great!!

Comment: So you can just accept it as your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference the <section>
const dropDown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");

// Register the "mouseenter/leave" events to <section>
dropDown.addEventListener("mouseenter", drop);
dropDown.addEventListener("mouseleave", drop);

/**
 * Event handler passes the (e)vent object by default
 * >> If the triggered event is "mouseenter", add "active" class to "this",
 * which is the tag registered to the "mouseenter" event 
 * (<section> aka .dropdown), and then end function
 * >> Otherwise, remove "active" class.
 */
function drop(e) {
  if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
    return this.classList.add("active");
  }
  this.classList.remove("active");
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  /* font-size on <html> will be referenced by the rem unit */
  font: 300 2ch/1.25 "Segoe UI"
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  /* 
  Add this to the parent of .dropdown to prevent a sudden shift to the 
  left 
  */
  overflow: scroll;
}

.dropdown {
  /* 
  This will make all absolute positioned children reference the
  <section>'s borders in regards to it's own position (eg <menu>)
  */
  position: relative;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 1em;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

menu {
  /*
  As an absolutely positioned child of <section>, it's position
  (top, bottom, left, right, and z-index) is referenced to <section>
  */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

li {
  /* As default, each <li> is flat and invisible */
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  /* This animates the expansion and compression */
  transition: 0.4s ease-in;
}

.active menu {  
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.active li {
  /* 
  When <section> has the "active" class, each <li> will expand
  and show itself
  */
  height: 1.25rem;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!--
  Wrap everything in a block level tag and treat it as the "dropdown"
-->
<section class="dropdown">
  <button>Hover</button>
  <menu>
    <!-- 
      Only <ul>, <ol>, and <menu> can have <li> as children 
    -->
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
  </menu>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

II think you only need these two functions to get what you want

```
 button.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
    dropdown.classList.add("active")
 })
 dropdown.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
     dropdown.classList.remove("active")
 })
```

Try mouseleave in the layer dropdown to remove the class